# Is it possible to send an email with Swiftmailer that does not register in the "sent messages" on gmail?

Tags: symfony4, swiftmailer

I build an application using the framework Symfony 4 and when creating a new user I program sends an email containing a password generated randomly. However this mail is saved in the mailbox that I use for the sent in the directory "sent messages" of gmail. Is there an option to not save the message?